# Is there a possible connection between the two different meanings (forest, ruler) of the Old English word 'weald'?

Tags: etymology, old-english

The old english word for 'forest' is weald, yet the old english word for 'ruler' is also weald.

What could be a possible explanation for this? Is there a possible connection between the two meanings of the same word?

Answer (score 1):

> What could be a possible explanation for this?

Coincidence and homonyms

The OED gives

> Weald (n.):

**Etymology**: Old English weald ‘forest’ (the West Saxon equivalent of Anglian wald : see wold n.), normally developing into southern Middle English wēld(e , weeld ; the modern spelling, which is due to Lambarde, is a re-adoption of the Old English form. The form wild(e , which occurs early in the 16th cent., is probably parallel to Kentish and Sussex dialect fild for field , but in later use was apparently assimilated in pronunciation to the more intelligible wild n., which had an appropriately descriptive meaning.

> The Old English weald is applied in the Chronicle (see below) to the forest of Andred, which included at least part of the present ‘Weald’.

Cf Modern German "wald" - wood/forest

> † wield, n.
>
> Etymology: Probably shortened < Old English geweald, gewield, i-wald n.
>
> 1.a. Command, control; governance. Chiefly in at, in, on (one's) wield.
>
> α.
>
> OE   tr. Orosius Hist. (Tiber.) (Dict. Old Eng. transcript) (1980) iv. xi. 109   Þa Antiochus þæt gehyrde, þa bæd he Scipian friþes, & him his sunu ham onsende, se wæs on his wealde [eOE B.L. Add. gewealde].

Cf Modern German Gewalt - power

Comment: It's also worth noting that the noun *weald* (rule) is related to the verb *wealdan* (to rule). As far as I know, *weald* (forest) doesn't have that. Context usually distinguishes the two,  like other homonyms.